# Comparing Empty Objects

Tags: java

I have a following Question 
   i have two empty Objects and i am using equals() method to compare them, as we know equals method compare contents of an Object, but in this case i dont have any properties to my Object

```
   Object ob1 = new Object();
   Object ob2 = new Object();
    if(ob1.equals(ob2)){
        System.out.println(" they are Equal");
    }
    else{ 
        System.out.println("not equal");
    }
    if(ob1 == ob2){
        System.out.println(" they are Equal");
    }
    else{ 
        System.out.println("not equal");
    }
```

we know == will compare the references of the Objects

what will equals method compare here ??

thanks in Advance ...

Comment: Sorry - had to vote down because this is clearly answered in the JavaDocs.

Comment: `equals()` doesn't compare the contents of the objects as you think it does. It compares objects using the implementation of `equals()` in the class of the object on which it's invoked. And this `equals()` method can do various different things depending on the type of the object. In the case of `Object`, `equals()` considers two instances equal if they are the exact same instance.

Comment: It does same thing as `==` operator. Look at `Objest.equals` sources.

Comment: @aim: no need to look at the sources. It's documented in the javadoc.

Comment: Nick Holt -- No Problem ,  JB Nizet -- thanks for the Answer..

Comment: @JBNizet I'm agree with you :)

Answer (score 3):

From the [Object.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) JavaDoc:

*The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).*

Answer (score 2):

It will also compare references, as stated [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:
>
> It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
> It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
> It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.
> It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the objects is modified.
> For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

Answer (score 1):

If both Objects are `null` then

```
 if(ob1==null && ob2==null)
```

If you try to do `ob1.equals(null)` you will get `NullPointerException`. Since ob1 it self `null`.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. == operator compare reference or memory location of objects in heap, whether they point to same location or not.
> 2. equals() method main purpose is two compare the state of two objects or contents of the object.

But you are using `Object` class `equals()` method.

> Object class default implementation of equals() method  work like == ,means it will check the memory reference of the object if they point to same location.

Note:
This default implementation is overridden to do content comparision in classes like String,Wrapper classes.

Answer (score 0):

While there is some inconsistency about what `X.equals(Y)` should mean (i.e. what "question" should it answer), two useful questions are:

- When the object is used as intended, should replacing some references to `X` with references to `Y` be expected not to change their behavior?
- When the object is used as intended, would swapping *all* references to `X` with references to `Y`, *and vice versa*, be expected not to change their behavior?

If `Object` defined `hashCode()` to return the same value for all empty objects, and `equals` to return true when comparing any two empty objects to each other, those definitions would have satisfied #1.  On the other hand, any object which defines `equals` to test reference equality and `hashCode` to return `identityHashCode` will *also* satisfy #1 (if `X` and `Y` are distinct instances, the fact that `X.equals(X)` is true but `Y.equals(X)` is false is, in and of itself, good reason to regard the objects as distinct.

While it's debatable whether `Object` should have been a concrete type, the *only* use of an instance of `Object` is as an identity token.  As such, that fact that `Object` is a concrete type implies that its `equals` methods should test identity.